# error in getting pandas time series data into mysql database on localhost

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pymysql

I am trying to retrieve data from National Stock Exchange for a given Scrip name.

I already have created a database name "NSE" in MySQL. But did not create any table.

Following script I am using to retrieve per minute data from the NSE website (let's say I want to retrieve data for scrip (stock) 'CYIENT'.

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import pymysql

#database connection
conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="pwd123", database="NSE")
c = conn.cursor()

your_key = "WLLS3TVOG22C6P9J"
def stockchart(symbol):
    ts = TimeSeries(key=your_key, output_format='pandas')
    data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol=symbol,interval='1min', outputsize='full')
    sql.write_frame(data, con=conn, name='NSE', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
    print(data.head())
    data['close'].plot()
    plt.title('Stock chart')
    plt.show()

symbol=input("Enter symbol name:")
stockchart(symbol)

#commiting the connection then closing it.
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

On running the above script I am getting following errors:

```
'sql' is not defined.
```

Also I am not sure if the above script will also create a table in NSE for (user input) stock 'CYIENT'.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering, I hope the code is a mock, not the real code. Otherwise, I'd suggest to change your credentials.

Now, I believe you are trying to use [`pandas.io.sql.write_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.sql.write_frame.html) (for `pandas<=0.13.1`). However, you forgot to import the module, thus the interpreter doesn't recognize the module `sql`. To fix it just add

```
from pandas.io import sql
```

to the begining of the script.

Notice the parameters you use in the function call. You use `if_exists='replace'`, so the table `NSE` will be dropped and recreated every time you run the function. It will contain whatever `data` contains.

Comment: thanks for suggestions @tmrlvi no issues with credentials, they can be re-produced. but will my code still produce tables in DB?

Comment: got an error `AttributeError: module 'pandas.io.sql' has no attribute 'write_frame'`

Comment: What version of pandas do you have? It was changed after 13.0 to be the method `to_sql` of the dataframe. (That is, use `data.to_sql` instead)